# Python regex: "like" regex pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I have this pattern: `^[0-2]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$`. It checks if entered string is of time format, like `01:20`, `20:30` etc. The thing is, I need to check if value being entered is correct by symbol. Because if user starts entering time and he enters first symbol, regex will not pass automatically, because let say `1` does not match that pattern.

I mean let say someone starts entering input like:

`1`, then `0`, then `:`. It means regex check should still pass, because user is entering correct symbols in a sequence.

But if he let say entered:

`1`, `0`, `:`, then `a`, regex should fail at the point when he entered `a`, because part of time that was entered is not correct: `10:a` will never match that final regex.

So is there some way with regex to match pattern in a `like` way. Usually how search works, if you entered correct phrase, it will find you results by that.

Code snippet that is working for only "final" value:

```
In [32]: import re

In [33]: p = re.compile(r'^[0-2]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$')

In [34]: p
Out[34]: re.compile(r'^[0-2]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$')

In [35]: p.search('01:')

In [36]: p.search('01:10')
Out[36]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x7f163153cf38>
```

Comment: on the other hand a partial matching like `p.search('01')` doesn't guarantee that  the input string points to *time format*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest well, as long as user is entering correct symbols in a sequence, its OK. If he enters anything incorrect in a sequence, he will actually won't be able to enter it, because check will forbid to pass that symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably specify a valid 'template', and check that replacing the first characters of that with the users input matches the regex.

```
REGEX = re.compile(r'^[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$')
TEMPLATE = '00:00'

def check_partial_input(chars):
    test_str = chars + TEMPLATE[len(chars):]
    return bool(REGEX.search(test_str))
```

I think this does what you intend:

```
>>> check_partial_input("1")
True
>>> check_partial_input("a")
False
>>> check_partial_input("01:")
True
>>> check_partial_input("01:a")
False
```

The drawback is that it doesn't work well with things like optional characters in the regex (you'll notice I made the first number required)